# How to insert an image in DataGrid near a texblock

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to insert an image near a textblock. I've a series of teams and I want add the shield of this teams near their names. So in the WPF i made this structure:

```
<DataGrid x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="League_DataGrid" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,368,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="181" Width="676" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns >
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = 'position'}" Header="Posizione" CanUserResize="False" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Squadra">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path='name'}"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Path='logo'}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = 'points'}" Header="Punti" CanUserResize="true" MinWidth="150" MaxWidth="200" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = 'playedGames'}" Header="Partite Giocate" CanUserResize="False" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = 'goals'}" Header="Goal" CanUserResize="False" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = 'goalsAgainst'}" Header="Goal Subiti" CanUserResize="False" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path = 'goalsDifference'}" Header="Differenza Reti" CanUserResize="False" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

So, in the c# code, I've created a function that populate the DataGrid.

```
                int i=0;
                foreach (var classifica in leagueTable_Object.standing)
                {
                    MainWindow.AppWindow.League_DataGrid.Items.Add(new LeagueTable.Classifica
                    {
                        position = classifica.position,
                        name = classifica.teamName,
                        logo = SvgReader.Load(new MemoryStream(new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadData(Teams.team_struct[i].logo))),
                        playedGames = classifica.playedGames,
                        goals = classifica.goals,
                        goalsAgainst = classifica.goalsAgainst,
                        goalsDifference = classifica.goalDifference
                    });
                    i++;
                }
```

The problem is that when I execute this code I get this exception:

```
XmlException was not managed.
```

[image]

What I doing wrong?
StackTrace:

```
    Eccezione generata: 'System.Xml.XmlException' in System.Xml.dll
   in System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   in System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)
   in System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.InvalidCharRecovery(Int32& bytesCount, Int32& charsCount)
   in System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.GetChars(Int32 maxCharsCount)
   in System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ReadData()
   in System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.SwitchEncoding(Encoding newEncoding)
   in System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.SwitchEncodingToUTF8()
   in System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseXmlDeclaration(Boolean isTextDecl)
   in System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   in System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   in System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   in Svg2Xaml.SvgReader.Load(XmlReader reader, SvgReaderOptions options)
   in Svg2Xaml.SvgReader.Load(Stream stream, SvgReaderOptions options)
   in Svg2Xaml.SvgReader.Load(Stream stream)
   in Test.LeagueTable.load_League_Table() in C:\Users\Anto\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Test\Test\LeagueTable.cs:riga 117
```

Comment: Check the stack trace of the XmlException. In all likelihood that exception is completely unrelated to the XAML of your UI. I would not be surprised if the exception is coming from the SvgReader...

Comment: In the stack trace there is this message: invalid character in the specified encoding. row 1, position 1.
System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal ...
Anyway I'm just trying to load an image in a DataGrid by url taken from team_struct, but maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: A [stack trace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is different from the message of an exception...

Comment: Oh sorry. I've edited the question with the stacktrace.

Comment: Well, exactly as i guessed: `in Svg2Xaml.SvgReader.Load(Stream stream)`... there is the evidence that your problem is unrelated to WPF. Rather, the SvgReader has some problem with the SVG data it tries to read and parse, i.e. the SVG data has some kind of XML error (either the data is no SVG at all, or it is corrupted data)

Comment: There is another method to insert the image in the DataGrid downloading the image by Internet?

Comment: I don't know. I have never dealt with using SVGs in WPF applications, unfortunately. Would it be a possible alternative to let the server provide PNGs instead SVGs (because WPF has built-in support for PNGs)? If you want/need to stick with SVG but find the Svg2Xaml package unfit for your particular purpose, then i guess Google is your best friend... :(